# Probability: If E1 is included in E2, show that P(E1)<=P(E2).

Tags: probability

Really simple question but I cannot figure out the proof.
If E1 is included in E2, how do I show that P(E1)<=P(E2)?

Comment: What's your level? How was probability introduced to you?

Comment: I am taking a basic probability course. We should be able to prove this using the axioms of probability.

Comment: So what are your axioms?

Comment: Hint: You should have around three (as Kolmogorov's probability theory does).  What are the ones *you* use in your course?  How do you think they might be relevant?

Comment: These are my axioms:
i. P(S) = 1
ii. 0 ≤ P(E) ≤ 1
iii. If E1 and E2 are disjoint then P(E1 U E2) = P(E1) + P(E2)

Comment: Ok.  so take $E_1$ and define $F=E_2-E_1$ (the complement of $E_1$ in $E_2$).  What is $E_1\cap F$?  What can you say about its probability?

Comment: You have $E_1 \subset E_2$. Draw a figure. Can you pick two disjoint sets out of the figure? Apply the third axiom to them and you have $P(E_2) = P(E_1) + P(\text{something})$, now use the second axiom.

Comment: Well then (i) we're not dealing with the (entire) sample space, (ii) is useful to show $P(E_1) \leq P(E_1)+\text{something positive} = P(E_2)$, (iii) would be useful if that something were the probability of ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your third point says that for disjoint events, the probabilities are additive.

Then, we can do this : $E_1$ and $E_1^c \cap E_2$ are disjoint events. Hence, we can sum them up: $P(E_1 \cup (E_1^c \cap E_2)) = P(E_1) + P(E_1^c \cap E_2)$.

Now, note that $ P(E_1^c \cap E_2) \geq 0$, and also, $E_1 \cup (E_1^c \cap E_2) = E_2$, because $E_1 \subset E_2$. Hence, we get $P(E_2) \geq P(E_1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$E_2 = E_1 \cup E_3$$ where $$E_3 = E_2-E_1.$$ Notice that $$E_1 \cap E_3 = \emptyset$$ According to  first Kolmogorov axiom, we always have $P(E)\ge0$, and according to the third axiom, for two non-intersecting sets $A$ and $B$, $P(A \cup B) = P(A)+P(B)$.
Therefore $$P(E_2) = P(E_3 \cup E_1) = P(E_3) + P(E_1) \ge P(E_1).$$

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to prove that your third axiom is true for any finite collection of pairwise disjoint sets. Then, note that the three sets $E_1\cap E_2$, $E_1\setminus E_2$ and $E_2\setminus E_1$ are disjoint. Lastly, use the fact that $E_1\subseteq E_2$ to simplify the descriptions of the above sets.